# page not found Netlify deploy

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, netlify

I am trying to deploy a simple portfolio website built with HTML, SCSS and JS on Netlify but getting a page not found error after deployment. I have 3 folders,

1. files/ where css, images, and js files are.
2. pages/ where index.html, about.html etc are.
3. scss/ where main.scss is.

Now, when I deploy a website and visit a link, I get page not found error. But when I add /pages to the link, my site works.
I tried putting /pages in the base directory but then I only see the html page without any css.
I also tried putting everything in files/ folder, but the problem is still the same.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue? I shall be thankful to you.

Comment: Have you tried adding the index.html file in the root directory?

Comment: @Prana thanks for your suggestion, it worked. Thanks everyone else too for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking their build configuration to check if your site's configuration is correct? The documentation on that matter can be found [here](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/overview/).

Comment: Yes I went through this document. There is no build script in package.json instead just a sass script which runs using npm run sass and site works locally. And when I deploy on Netlify, it works only when I add /pages to the netlify link I receive.

Answer (score 0):

Are you uploading main.scss or style.css.
As you have to link style.css

Answer (score -2):

Change your main HTML file to Index.html. It will definitely work.